# Are H1, title, and meta tags mandatory on a 404 error page?

Tags: seo, html, 404, meta-tags, error

404 error page is not used to enhance SEO (see: https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/2445990), so does it really necessary to have the H1 tag, a page title, a meta description, and a breadcrumb trail?

Answer (score 1):

As described in your reference link, Google never indexed the 404 error page that never existed on your site, so whatever is on that page will never impact the SEO.

But for the user experience I think it's good to add a breadcrumb trail and other tag that can help visitor.

Comment: The 404 page shouldn't be in your navigation hierarchy and it appears on an infinite set of URLs.   I'm not sure how you would determine what breadcrumbs would be appropriate for it.

Comment: @StephenOstermiller I didn't mean 404 pages on the nav hierarchy, but the 404 page has navigation like main navigation, back button, go to category if it's known, related product/post(just like question on SO/SE that deleted) etc.

Comment: For the breadcrumbs, maybe we can just fill them with a home and back link/button.